# opposite return of the function

Tags: python, function, boolean

I am doing some Python exercisses and for some reason my fucntion is returning to me opposite bool value. If statement under the function need to has "not" to work properly - can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

```
number = int(input("Enter numbers you want to check: "))


def dividers(number):
temp_tab = range(2, number)
divider = 0

for x in temp_tab:
    while number % x == 0:
        divider += 1
        if divider > 1:
            return False
        else:
            return True


if not dividers(number):
   print("It is a prime number")
else:
   print("It is not a prime number")
```

Comment: can you provide some input and expected output?

Comment: Because the logic of your `dividers` function is incorrect. You are always only ever returning after the first iteration (when x = 2)

Comment: Because your function is defined to return False if there are more than one divider hence the number is not prime.

Comment: What is the requirement? Do you want a function that checks if a number is prime and return True in that case? Or do you want a function that checks if a number has multiple dividers (hence it is not prime)?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that every number has at least 2 dividers so if there is one more it won't be prime number.

Comment: I want to check if they amount of dividers is more than 1 (+2 in mind) and return False but if there wont be dividers it should return True

Comment: So you want an `is_prime` function?

Comment: basicly yes that's what I want

Comment: I added an answer without any of the counting of `dividers`. It does the work. But if you absolutely want the `divider` counting in, tell me. (Also why in you code you had a `while` loop inside your `for` loop?)

Comment: Tought I need this while to count dividers in for loop, but your answear is actually exactly what i was trying to achieve

Comment: OK. Note the update. I wasn't checking for negative, 0, and 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want a function to check if a number is prime:

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number <= 1: return False

    for x in range(2, number):
        if number % x == 0:
            return False
    return True


number = int(input("Enter numbers you want to check: "))

if is_prime(number):
    print("It is a prime number")
else:
    print("It is not a prime number")
```